# Is it bad for a stock to be on the Regulation SHO threshold list?

Tags: united-states, stocks, shorting-securities, sec

I have been reading up on [Regulation SHO](https://www.sec.gov/investor/pubs/regsho.htm), and I have found some lists of stocks on the Regulation SHO "threshold list": [SEC:
Fails-to-Deliver Data](https://www.sec.gov/data/foiadocsfailsdatahtm), and [OTC Markets:
Reg SHO Data](https://www.otcmarkets.com/market-activity/reg-sho-data). However, I am unable to understand the implications for a stock to be listed on the threshold list.

From the point of view of a long-term buy-and-hold retail investor, is it bad for a stock to be on the Regulation SHO threshold list? If so, how? What is the significance of that list from the retail investor's point of view?